# How to create Custom Property for DVWP (Data View WebPart)?

Tags: 2010, data-view-web-part

In my solution I have to create DVWP in which user can enter Row Limit as Property and that amount of rows will be displayed in WebPart.

I used built In Functionality of DVWP for Setting Row limit but that's not my solution.

Can any body Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it using code but here's its happening in this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/working-with-data-view-web-part-in-sharepoint-list/), they are setting row limits using UI.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I have already done this thing. I want functionality like End User can Set row limit by using Web Part Property.